# How can I typeset function names as they appear in algorithmic environments?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, inline

I'm using the `algorithmicx` package and I'd like to mention a function in common text. Is there a way to do that, or do I have to make a format that mimics the one used in the algorithm (all caps monospace)?

Something like `$ ... $` does for math, but for algorithms.

In the example below, I want to refer to `CalculateCovariance` in the text and I want it to be typeset using the same style as in the algorithm.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{IncrementalGN}{${\boldsymbol \theta}, {\bf v}, {\bf r}, {\bf z}_u, \Sigma_u, tol, it_{max}$}
\State $(\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}, \hat{\bf r}) = \Call{Update}{{\boldsymbol \theta}, {\bf v}, {\bf r}, {\bf z}_u, \Sigma_u}$
\State $(\hat\Lambda, \hat{\boldsymbol \eta}, A_u) = \Call{LinearSystem}{\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}\;, \hat{\bf r}}$

\State $changedLP = \textsc{false}$
\For{$it = 0$ \textbf{to} $it_{max}$}
    \State $ {\boldsymbol \delta} = \Call{Solve}{\hat\Lambda, \hat{\boldsymbol \eta}} $
    \If{$norm({\boldsymbol \delta}) < tol$}
        \State ${\bf break}$
    \EndIf
    \State $\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}\;\leftarrow \hat{\boldsymbol \theta} \oplus {\boldsymbol \delta}$
    \State $(\hat\Lambda, \hat{\boldsymbol \eta}) = \Call{LinearSystem}{\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}, \hat{\bf r}}$
    \State $changedLP = \textsc{true}$ % we have just optimized, L needs to be rebuilt    
\EndFor
\Statex \Comment a simple incremental Gauss-Newton solver

\State $ordering = \Call{AMD}{\hat\Lambda}$
\State $\hat R = \Call{Chol}{\hat\Lambda, ordering}$ %%legit\Comment the $\hat R$ factor may be reused, if available in the solver

\If{$changedLP$}
    \State $\hat\Sigma = \Call{CalculateCovariance}{\hat R, ordering}$
\Else
    \State $\hat\Sigma = \Call{UpdateCov}{\Sigma, \hat R, ordering, A_u, {\bf v}}$ % UpdateCovariance was too long
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{\label{alg:seeifrelin} Covariance Recovery Algorithm Selection}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will `\verb||` or `\texttt{}` work? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2790/32374

Comment: @darthbith no, those are typewriter, and the style is different from the one used in `algorithmicx` to typeset function names (see e.g. images in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/mark-a-pseudocode-block-and-insert-comments-near-it it is all caps and the capital letters would use a slightly larger font)

Comment: See the page 4  of `listings` package manual (1.2 Typesetting listings\Code snippets). you can use `\lstinline$var i:integer;$` [manual here](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)

Comment: Are you sure its monospace? Anyways, `\textsc{}` will get you small capitals :-) You could even mix `\texttt{\textsc{}}` (I think) and get typewriter small caps if your font supports it. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46699/32374

Comment: @CarlosLanziano unfortunately `\lstinline$\Function{myFun}$` typesets `\Function{myFun}` in the text, in normal font - I only want `myFun` to appear.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we know exactly what you're referring to. At the moment, whether you're referring to the style of an algorithm caption or that of something else is unclear.

Comment: @theswine. hi!. You can use `\lstinline` and the math mode. Try, for example, `\def\Fuction{myfun=1, i=i++}\lstinline[mathescape]!${\Fuction}$!`. Or changing the font style: `\def\Fuction{myfun=1, i=i++}\lstinline[mathescape]!$\mathrm{\Fuction}$!` And please, add a MWE.

Comment: @CarlosLanziano Listings and algorithms are not the same thing. What you're suggesting would be semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the source code of the [`algpseudocode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty) package, look for the definitions of the macros used for typesetting functions and procedures:

```
\algdef{SE}[PROCEDURE]{Procedure}{EndProcedure}%
   [2]{\algorithmicprocedure\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicprocedure}%
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
   [2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%
```

You can see that some `\textproc` macro is used to typeset the name of the function/procedure. For information, that macro is defined (in `algpseudocode`) as follows,

```
\algnewcommand\textproc{\textsc}
```

where `\algnewcommand` is simply `\newcommand` with a twist.

However, you shouldn't just use `\textsc` to typeset function/procedure names in the main text; using `\textproc` is preferable, from a semantic point of view.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{AIP}\label{AIPal}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{Bisection}{$f,a,b,\epsilon$}
    \State foo
    \State bar
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

The \textproc{Bisection} algorithm shows blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, *exactly* what I needed.

Comment: How to properly call a defined function is other algorithms? Is there something like \Call{Bisection(...)} ?

Comment: how can this be done in algorithm2e package?