# Change font for function names within algorithmic

Tags: fonts, algorithmic

Using the following code, the function name foo is printed as `\textsc{foo}`.

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{foo}{$a$}
    \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}
```

How can I change this to `\texttt{foo}` for all `\Function` and `\Call` commands?

Comment: very closely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203713/how-can-i-typeset-function-names-as-they-appear-in-algorithmic-environments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The needed package is `algpseudocode`, not `algorithmic`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algrenewcommand\textproc{\texttt}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{foo}{$a$}
    \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]